# How can I split a 8 byte array into two four byte arrays in Python?

Tags: python, loops, byte

what would be the fastest way to put the first 4 bytes of an 8 byte array in one array and the last 4 bytes in another one.

My approach was to create a for loop and then extract everything. Like this

```
for i in range(0,7):
    if i < 4:
        ...
    else
        ...
```

There has to be something more efficient. What am I missing?

Comment: what object do you call `byte array`? and what do you optimise, number of lines, excetuion time, something else?

Comment: Your `for` loop doesn't do anything with the last byte. You should type in `range(0,7)` at a Python 2 command line (or `list(range(0,7))` at a Python 3 command line) and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slices:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
A[0:4]
A[4:8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
hi, lo = some_array[:4], some_array[4:]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = range(0,8)
b = a[:4]
c = a[4:]
```

Easiest way I know.

Answer (score 0):

List slicing is your friend here ;)

```
array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

firstpart,secondpart = (array[:4],array[4:])

print firstpart
[0, 1, 2, 3]
print secondpart
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```